# Adding Html controls at runtime using Asp MVC 2 Rc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add Html controls in runtime using Microsoft MVC2 RC2 to create a dynamic data entry form.

(Preferably also supporting the UIHint feature)

What is the recommended way of doing this?

Best Regards,
Rune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such notion as controls in an mvc application as it is in a WebForms application. There are models, controllers, views, subviews, helpers. So I guess you could either add them using javascript or create a model containing all the necessary information so that at runtime an html helper or a subview will be capabale of generating the corresponding HTML for these controls from this model.